# Como saber el estado del response en un fetch? en fetch api javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

```
function boleta(){
    var check = false;
    var formboleta = new FormData();
    formboleta.append("num_boleta", data2.boletas[id].num_boleta);
    formboleta.append("created_at", data2.boletas[id].created_at);
    formboleta.append("total", data2.boletas[id].total);
    //arreglo id productos
    for(let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
        formboleta.append("productos", data2.boletas[id].productos[k].id);
    }
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formboleta,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("La_ip_va_aqui", requestOptions)
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Hola, quisiera saber como obtener el estado de response, para luego llamar a otra función si el estado de respuesta es 200, está función es cliente();.

cliente solo se ejecutará si el resulado de este fetch es 200 o ok.

Comment: En el primer `.then()` puedes analizar la propiedad `ok` para saber que la respuesta fue exitosa: `.then(response => {if(response.ok) { return response.json(); } throw 'Error en petición'; })`. Si llegaste hasta el segundo `.then()` quiere decir que la respuesta fue exitosa y el contenido se pudo interpretar como JSON.

Comment: ya, pero como a partir de si el response es exitoso puedo ejecutar otra función? en este caso cliente();

Comment: me salio este error Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El status de la promesa del `fetch` se lee de `response.status`, la promesa además resuelve `ok` como `true` si el status esta entre 200 y 299, para otros códigos retorna `false` (50x, 40x). Si la petición no puede realizarse, por ejemplo porque no se accede a la red, o el dominio no existe (no solo el recurso, que sería 404 ) se lanza una exepción.

Sin status:

```js
fetch(' http://api_que_no_existe.com/api/v1')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status) // <-- No tiene status, ni siquiera pasa por aca
      console.log(response.ok)
      
      response.ok && console.log("ejectutamos cliente")
      
      return response.json()
    }

  )
  .then(data => console.log("aqui los datos"))// <-- Tampoco pasa por aca
  .catch(error=> console.log("Hay un error que no está entre 200 y 50x"));
```

Con status:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status) //<-- Tiene status
      console.log(response.ok)

      response.ok && console.log("ejectutamos cliente") // <-- status entre 200-299

      return response.json()
    }

  )
  .then(data => console.log("aqui los datos")) // <-- Aqui si esta data
  .catch(error => console.log("Hay un error que no está entre 200 y 50x"));
```

Los errores que retornan las APIs muchas veces vienen con un status 200, cuando deberían responder el código que corresponde (400 bad request, 422 Unprocessable Entity, etc), en ese caso hay que además chequear la propiedad correspondiente del objeto devuelto, la especificación de una api RESTfull json está descripta en [jsonapi.org](https://jsonapi.org/examples/), en donde se indicarían los formatos teóricamente apropiados para la norma.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer `.then()` puedes analizar la [propiedad ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) para saber que la respuesta fue exitosa e interpretar como JSON o, en su defecto, lanzar un error.

Si llegaste hasta el segundo .then() quiere decir que la respuesta fue exitosa y el contenido se pudo interpretar como JSON y puedes usarlo para ejecutar la otra función.

```
function boleta(){
    var check = false;
    var formboleta = new FormData();
    formboleta.append("num_boleta", data2.boletas[id].num_boleta);
    formboleta.append("created_at", data2.boletas[id].created_at);
    formboleta.append("total", data2.boletas[id].total);
    //arreglo id productos
    for(let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
        formboleta.append("productos", data2.boletas[id].productos[k].id);
    }
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formboleta,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("La_ip_va_aqui", requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
        // La petición fue exitosa, estado HTTP = 200
        if(response.ok) {
            // Interpretar como JSON y pasarlo al segundo .then()
            // Si esto falla, en consola aparecerá un error
            return response.json();
        }
        // Lanzar error, será capturado en .catch()
        throw 'Error en petición';
    })
    .then(data => {
        // data es un objeto JSON, puedes usarlo para llamar otra función
        cliente(data);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```